Solving the integral $ \int\limits^{c+i\infty}_{c-i\infty} \dfrac{k^{-s}}{D_{-s}(z) e^{z^2/4}}ds $
My question is if the following integral can be expressed in terms of trascendent functions:
$
\int\limits^{c+i\infty}_{c-i\infty} \dfrac{k^{-s}}{D_{-s}(z) e^{z^2/4}}ds
$
where $0<c<1$, $k>0$ and $D_{-s}(z)$ is a complex-generalized version of the parabollic cylinder function,
$
D_{-s}(z):=\dfrac{e^{-z^2/4}}{\Gamma(s)}\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-zt}t^{s-1} e^{-t^2/2}dt \quad\;\forall\Re(s)>0,z>0
$
with $z$ real.
If it cannot, at least I would like to obtain (as tight as possible) upper and lower bounds on it, given by functions of $k$ and $z$. I have tried deriving those bounds interchanging the order of both integrals and using inequalities (of Jensen's type, sort of), but still I get integrals for those bounds that I cannot solve.

I don't know the answer, but to simplify the problem a tiny bit you can take the $e^{z^2/4}$ outside the integral, since it does not depend on the integration variable $s$

Thanks Dennis, I just put the $e^{z^2/4}$ so it cancels with the one in the definition of the parabollic cylinder function, in case it was useful for someone.  In fact, $D_{-s}(z)e^{z^2/4}=2^{s/2} H_{-s}(z/\sqrt{2})$ where $H$ is an Hermite polynomial,  but extended for complex indices with negative real part (defined in terms of hypergeometric functions, if you wish). Anyway, I have tried it from different angles and cannot advance much, hoping someone comes up with an idea.

The question is also related to this other question through some technical transformations based on Fredholm integral equations and inverse Mellin transforms
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4981421/deriving-the-probability-distribution-function-of-inf-limits-t0-fracw-t-q
