Deriving the probability distribution function of $i_s:=\inf\limits_{t<s}\frac{(W_t-q)^2}{kt}$
where $k>1$ and $q>0$ are real constants and $W_t$ is a standard brownian motion. A lesser version of the problem, that would also help me, would be to look for the pdf of $i_s$ but for a Brownian bridge such that $W_0=0$ and $W_s=y$. I cannot come up with an idea, like the reflection principle, to apply to this case and use ordinary tools of stochastic calculus. My thoughts would be that we could seize something like Girsanov's theorem to make a probability measure change so that $Z_t=(W_t-q)$ is  a process of well characterized properties under the new measure, then another change of measure so that $Y_t=Z_t/\sqrt(t)$ is also a well known process, such that the distribution of the infimum of its square is well known. Nevertheless, the second change of measure (for $Y_t$) is difficult to implement due to the behavior of $\sqrt{t}$ at $t=0$.
I am quite new to this field, but I cannot find anything in the literature that helps me solve this particular problem, so any suggestion would be recommended. My go-to books are Karatzas and Shreve for stochastic calculus, and Shiryaev's for an integro-differential equations approach, but, still, nothing.

The question is related to this other question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4981413/solving-the-integral-int-limitsci-infty-c-i-infty-dfrack-sd-s
via Fredholm differential equations and inverse Mellin transform.  However, it does not seem to simplify the problem.
